# CakePHP Search Tutorial

Tags: cakephp, search

I am trying to setup a search function that will allow me to search text on 2 fields in my MySQL db.

All the tutorials I have found have either been very old, or look to be too complex just to do a search on a couple of fields and output the results.

Can anyone point me in the direction of a good tutorial or give me any tips to accomplish this search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `find()` command like Piotr said, you can also use `LIKE` to find results that are not exactly the text you entered.

```
$results = $this->Model->find('all', array('conditions' => array(
                                            'Model.field1 LIKE' => '%entered value%',
                                            'Model.field2 LIKE' => '%entered value%')));
```

This way when you search for "apple" you will also find "apple pie".

Answer (score 1):

Use a find() command.

If you want to find a specific text in two fields, you just have to do something like this:

```
$results = $this->Model->find('all', array('conditions' => array(
                                                'Model.field1' => 'expected value',
                                                'Model.field2' => 'expected value')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Function "Find" : http://book.cakephp.org/view/1018/find

Also videos in french : http://www.grafikart.fr/tutoriels/cakephp